# How to import template folder after a project has been created in unity with different template?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I have created a unity3D project using the standard unity 3d template in unity hub.
Now i want to add another scene to the project.
I want this scene to be the AR scene that unity provides in its AR template (the AR template you get when you create a new project as an AR project).
This AR scene is part of the AR template which contains also many scripts that relevant to the AR functionality.
A project that is created with the AR project template also automatically import some packages.
My project is a normal standard 3D project and i would like to add AR functionality to it.
So i imported to my simple 3D project all the packages that are automatically imported to the projects that are created with the AR template.
BUT i don't know what to do about all the other scripts and AR scene that come automatically with an AR project template.
These scripts and scene seem to only be availabe to projects that are created with the AR template from the get go.
These scripts and AR scene and other AR stuff are all bundled up in a folder called "ExampleAssets"
I dont know how to add this folder to my simple 3D project. This folder seem to only be available to projects that were initially created with the AR template in unity hub.
Any idea how i can get this "ExampleAssets" folder (which contain all the AR stuff) into my normal 3D project?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty project with AR template, [export everything (relevant stuff) to a Unitypackage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackagesCreate.html) and then [import](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackagesImport.html) that into your other project

This will export all the things you selected including dependencies etc. On the import side it will again give you control about which parts to import, by default it will automatically skip anything you already have there anyway or you have modified/differing from the import, so you can decide whether to skip those or overwrite with the imported versions.